# Obtaining total for associated columns

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 4 models, `User`, `ImageSize`, `Frame` and `CartItem`. The CartItem model holds all the id's for the 3 prior models, so

```
class CartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image_size
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :frame
end

create_table "cart_items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "image_size_id"
  t.integer  "frame_id"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cart_items
end
```

My first issue here is this doesn't seem correct, as in my association setup, but for now ill address that another time.

A Frame and ImageSize both have a `price` column and what I am trying to achieve is to get the sum of the price for Frame and ImageSize for the current user so that Ii can show a subtotal for the user that collects the sum for all cartitems

How can I write this query or collect this data? Here is what I have managed to put together, but surely there's an easier way?

```
def show
  @frame_total = CartItem.frame_price_total(current_or_guest_user)
  @image_size_total = CartItem.image_size_price_total(current_or_guest_user)
  @subtotal = CartItem.subtotal(@frame_total, @image_size_total)
end

class CartItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.frame_price_total(u)
    @price_array = []
    user = includes(:frame).where(user_id: u)
    user.each do |f|
      @price_array << f.frame.price
    end
    @price_array.sum
  end

 def self.image_size_price_total(u)
   @price_array = []
   user = includes(:image_size).where(user_id: u)
   user.each do |f|
     @price_array << f.image_size.price
   end
   @price_array.sum
end

def self.subtotal(image_size_total, frame_size_total)
  total = image_size_total + frame_size_total
  BigDecimal.new(total).to_s
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look good but have [N+1 query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) problem

```
   def show
    @user_frames = CartItem.includes(:frame).where(user_id: current_user)
    frame_array = []
    @user_frames.each do |f|
      frame_array << f.frame.price
    end
    @frame_total = frame_array.sum
  end
```